# What is the default kerberos credential cache on OSX?

Tags: macos, kerberos

I am trying to read the credential cache after I `kinit` from a script on OSX.

output from `klist` is as expected

```
$ klist
Credentials cache: API:<some uuid>
        Principal: <user@EXAMPLE>

  Issued                Expires               Principal
Nov  1 10:53:19 2019  Nov  1 18:53:17 2019  krbtgt/<user@EXAMPLE.COM>
```

How can I read these bytes from the default credential cache on OSX into my script so I can create a SPNEGO client to make requests with?  I can't find any filesystem location or mechanism available to me to read it.

Thanks!

Comment: The `klist` output is explicit: by default the cache uses `API:` protocol which seems to be proprietary. On Linux you would see `FILE:` or `KEYRING:`, on Windows you would not see much because the `klist.exe` from Microsoft implicitly uses proprietary `LSA:` while `klist.exe` from Java reverts to `FILE:` in case you want non-Microsoft auth.

Comment: How do you expect to _"create a SPNego client"_ from scratch? Try a version of `curl` compiled for OSX, with Kerberos/Negotiate support, I'm pretty sure it supports the native cache protocol.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter Sorry for poor wording.  I am using the gokrb5 library to initiate a 'client' using cache, but it doesn't seem to be able to read the default cache.  Obviously curl, chrome, firefox are all able to read it, so I am wondering how I can do the same.  I have no problem initiating a session utilizing a keytab or FILE cache I specify, but I would like to cut out the middleman and use the default OSX KCM cache

Comment: Unfortunately you will have to inspect the documentation (and possibly the source code) of that library to know which kinds of "credentials cache" are supported. The docs for standard _MIT Kerberos_ tools mention that _"`API` is only implemented on Windows"_... https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-1.15/doc/basic/ccache_def.html

Comment: PS: the bottom paragraph in that doc page indicates how to force your app to use a specific cache...

Answer (score 2):

For a similar use case, I ended up creating a new credentials cache by setting the cache path, and then reusing the cache:

```
# Original ticket:
$ klist
Credentials cache: API:097507D1-9D0A-4E7B-99AB-D1C625DA6BEE
        Principal: me@COMPANY.COM

  Issued                Expires               Principal
Sep  2 10:44:53 2022  Sep  2 20:44:53 2022  krbtgt/COMPANY.COM@COMPANY.COM

# Create a new ticket in a new location:
$ kinit --cache=my-new-location
$ klist --cache=my-new-location
Credentials cache: FILE:my-new-location
        Principal: me@COMPANY.COM

  Issued                Expires               Principal
Sep  2 10:45:11 2022  Sep  2 20:45:11 2022  krbtgt/COMPANY.COM@COMPANY.COM

# Keep using this cache:
$ export KRB5CCNAME="FILE:$(realpath my-new-location)"
$ klist --cache=my-new-location
Credentials cache: FILE:/Users/me/my-new-location
        Principal: me@COMPANY.COM

  Issued                Expires               Principal
Sep  2 10:45:11 2022  Sep  2 20:45:11 2022  krbtgt/COMPANY.COM@COMPANY.COM
```

Answer (score 1):

The default Kerberos tool of Mac is Heimdal. However, I think it's modified by Apple. I tried to find the cache file generated by the Mac Heimdal kinit, but I couldn't.

I think Apple deliberately hides it. It seems that the ticket cache is only accessed by API. The example is 'Ticket Viewer' application provided by Mac itself. https://computing.help.inf.ed.ac.uk/kerberos-mac-os-x

Answer (score -1):

It's supposed to be ==> FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_%{uid}

based on this documentation

https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-1.12/doc/mitK5defaults.html#paths

Comment: The default krb tool of Mac is not MIT but Heimdal. https://github.com/heimdal/heimdal